# Cakephp read user from session

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i have downloaded a php library or you can say a third party  module and put them into the app/Vendors folder.there is one php file in which i have to read the user from session .. 
well i am using auth component in my webapp ..so i dont how to import auth component  there and  how to read the user

at the moment the file is in this directory

```
app/Vendor/mynewlibrary/examples/bootstrap.php
```

and the other thing i want to mention here is that the bootstrap is not a class .. its a simple php file in which i need a userid.. i want to access the auth component here

Comment: If you want to access the AuthComponent directly, you should make a plugin instead of a file in the Vendor folder. You are creating a bootstrap.php so it seems like you should have used a Plugin anyway. [more info](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins)

Comment: Try just `var_dump($_SESSION)` from the bootstrap file itself? It should have the whole session there. Not recommended though, but it's an option.

Comment: @Jelmer well i am using a thirdparty library .. i dont have created the file by myself ..and i dont know how to make a plugin .. the library has many folders and files in it... but i need the user id in only one file

Comment: @LionelChan ok let me try it

Comment: @LionelChan yeah the session is in there but now how can i access the idUser ..it has bunch of arrays

Comment: Usually it's at `$_SERVER['Auth']['User']['id']`. `Auth` is a session key set by `AuthComponent` and the user array is in there.

Comment: @LionelChan thankyouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu it works .. thankyou ... well let me correct ur line i think u missed something "$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id']" this works for me ... please answer it so i can mark the answer

Comment: Oops yea sorry typo ;). Answer your own question then, and have it corrected ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done this in order to get the user information from session

```
     $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id']
```